# Explicit passing "this" parameter to method call

Tags: c++, c++11, std

Is it possible in c++ call class method with explicit passing first "this" param to it?

Something like this:

```
struct A
{
    void some() {} 
};

....

A a;
A::some(&a); // ~ a.some();
```

For reasonable question "WHY?": i need to implement std::bind analogue, and it works fine with constructions like this:

```
void f(int);
bind(f, 3);
```

but this doesn't work:

```
bind(&A::some, &a);
```

**UPDATE:**
Guys, my question is obviously not really clear. I know how to use std::bind, i want to know HOW is it processing constructions where this param explicitly passed to it: std::bind(&A::some, &a);

Comment: Look into member pointers to solve your `bind` problem.

Comment: Unless `A::some()` is static, there's no reason you would need to explicitly pass a `this` pointer...

Comment: No, that's not possible. If you show how you're currently implementing your `bind`, we might suggest extensions to make it work with member functions as well.

Comment: `bind(&A::some, &a);` should work. What goes wrong?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Obviously `bind(&A::some, &a);` would **not** actually invoke the member function. `bind(&A::some, &a)();` does though.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. I thought you were trying to use `std::bind`, not reinvent it.

Comment: i think the question title should be edited to include `bind` otherwise it sounds like a duplicate.IMO

Comment: `bind(&A::some, &a)` works just fine with `std::bind`. It's "just" a matter of template meta-programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an idea for a dispatcher which you could use inside your `bind`:

```
template <class R, class... Arg>
R call(R (*f)(Arg...), Arg &&... arg)
{ return f(std::forward<Arg>(arg)...); }

template <class C, class R, class... Arg>
R call(R (C::*f)(Arg...), C &c, Arg &&... arg)
{ return (c.*f)(std::forward<Arg>(arg)...); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like the following ?

```
struct A
{
    void some();
    static void some(A* that) { that->some(); } 
};

..

A a;
A::some(&a);
```